# any HL7 V2 field related to equipment manufacturer or model?

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Is there any HL7 V2 fields can be used to identify equipment and medical device manufacturer or model? In DICOM, there are some attributed such as "manufacturer", "model", "software" we can use to identify the vendor/model information of the device, is there any similar attributes in HL7 V2 message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an SDD segment "Sterilization Device Data" that has fields for device information. Although this may be designed for a specific type of device, you may be able to use it for more generic instruments.

```
SDD-1: Lot Number (EI) optional
SDD-2: Device Number (EI) optional
SDD-3: Device Name (ST) optional
SDD-4: Device Data State (IS) optional
SDD-5: Load Status (IS) optional
SDD-6: Control Code (NM) optional
SDD-7: Operator Name (ST) optional
```

You may look through the documentation at HL7 to see if there is something else that is more generic. Pick the HL7 version you need and download the spec. http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185

If you are interested in using the HAPI HL7 libraries for Java you can checkout the APIs here, which describe fields of HL7 segments. https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/v26/apidocs/index.html

If you don't find anything that suits your purpose, you can always make a custom z-segment to define the fields you need.